# Float right on 2 spans of same line, but need first span to be on left side

Tags: html, css, css-float

This is my HTML code

```
<span class="pull-right red">Text 1</span>
<span class="pull-right green">Text 2</span>
```

And My CSS is

```
.pull-right{
    float:right;
}
.red{
    color:red;
}
.green{
    color:green;
}
```

It is aligning **text 1** to right most on the line. I want the first span (that is **text 1**) to align left of second span.

[Here is JSFiddle Link.](http://jsfiddle.net/ytN2R/)

In the Case 1. I have provided my HTML.

In case 2 I have reordered the HTML. That is span text2 I have put first and text1 I have put second. Then I am getting the expected result. I can reorder it by JQuery. But I don't want to reorder the HTML.

So is there any way I can get the expecting result without reordering the HTML? Any CSS solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
  <div class="main">
     <span class="red">Text 1</span>
     <span class="green">Text 2</span>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.main
{
    float:right;
}

.red
{
    color:red;
}
.green
{
    color:green;
}
```

Comment: always add an explanation...these types of answers get down-voted at times as it promotes copy-paste answering! :)

Comment: What do you mean sir ?

Comment: you just posted the `html` and `css` without telling the probable cause for the problem....this is one of the most common problems in `bootstrap` found on SO...ny1 can copy and paste answers for it but explanation matters....doesn't it?? :)

Comment: thank you sir , but i am new here so i don't know how to answer

Answer (score 3):

Use your pull-right class on a wrapping div like this:

```
<div class="pull-right">
  <span class="red">Text 1</span>
  <span class="green">Text 2</span>
</div>
```

With the same css:

```
.pull-right{
    float:right;
}
.red{
    color:red;
}
.green{
    color:green;
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5BU2/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the two span tags in a `div` tag that has `float:right`.

**HTML**:

.....

```
<div class = "content">
  <span class="pull-left red">Text 1</span>
  <span class="pull-right green">Text 2</span>
</div>
```

...

**CSS:**:

```
.content{
  float:right;
}
.pull-right{
  float:right;
}
.pull-left{
  float:left;
}
```

Rest CSS remains same